# Ionic - Best practice: passing a callback to modal

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using an Ionic modal and I want to pass a callback function to it from the parent component. Since I'm creating the modal dynamically through TS, I am passing the callback as a nav param like so:

```
    const resetModal : Modal = this.modal.create('DeploymentConfigurationResetPage',
        { deployment: this.deployment, callback: this.hardResetCallback });
    resetModal.present();
```

And since I'm creating the modal through TS, I cannot pass the callback like this through a template:

```
<my-component  [callback]="showMessage"></my-component>
```

Is passing the callback through nav params ok or does that have a tendency for bugs? And if it's bad - what other way can I pass the callback?

Comment: Two questions.
1. When you will show that model?
2. Have you tried to access the callBack via viewChild()?

Comment: as an alternative you could use Events ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/ ). I don't know whats the better way just wnated to show you another way.

Comment: I don't really think viewChild() will work for this.

Comment: I will show the modal when the user click a button that opens it.